# How to use pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I opened pan doc but I do not know how to change the file to word? Actually I used the code but I do not know where it is saved or exactly works? Is it complicated?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply convert a `main.tex` file into a `main.docx` by:

1. Opening a new terminal in the folder where the `main.tex` is saved.
2. Typing `pandoc main.tex -o main.docx`

You now have the `main.docx` in your folder.

Comment: does not answer. figures and etc.